# Labelling layers with Python

Tags: arcpy, labeling

I need to turn labels on for previously used layer. 
Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
import sys
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = 1
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

fc_Mord = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Mord")[0]
if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
for lblClass in layer.labelClasses:
    lblClass.expression = "[ArcID]"
    layer.showLabels = True
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```

I want to use variable `fc_Mord` instead of layer name `Mord`, because user can name the layer (in previous steps) as he/she wants.

I have tried this, but it doesn't label the layer

```
tempLayer = "tempLayer"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_Mord, "tempLayer")

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, tempLayer)[0]
if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
for lblClass in layer.labelClasses:
    lblClass.expression = "[ArcID]"
    layer.showLabels = True
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edited code

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") #Map document reference
def label(fc_Mord, field):
   for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
       if lyr.name == fc_Mord:
           if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
               for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
                   lblClass.expression = "[ArcID]".format(field)
                   lyr.showLabels = True
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import arcpy
import sys
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = 1
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
attr_name = 'Attribute Name'

fc_Mord = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") #Map document reference
def label(fc_Mord, field):
   for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
       if lyr.name == fc_Mord:
           if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
               for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
                   lblClass.expression = "[{}]".format(field)
                   lyr.showLabels = True
label(fc_Mord, attr_name)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```

**Just specify attr_name variable.**

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function: i use it all the time it works great. Also you need to indent after your `if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):`

```
def label(layer):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        if lyr.name == layer:
            if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
                for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
                    lblClass.expression = "[ArcID]"
                    lyr.showLabels = True
```

you need to call the function after you initialize it

```
label(fc_Mord)
```

if you want "tempLayer" to be labeled then

```
label("tempLayer")
```

Comment: So, where I specify a layer i need to label? in a map document I have i.e. 5 layers, I need to pick one. that's why i set the variable `fc_Mord`. And in my case it is not necessary to set font...how and where can I use this function in my case?

Comment: Check my edit-ur Layer is the first item to be called in the function

Comment: Still no labels appearing. I will add the edited code in the question

Comment: which layer do you want to show labels? fc_Mord? or "tempLayer"?

Comment: I want to be labelled shp which user selects `fc_Mord = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)`